# fitting an ODE with python leastsq gives a cast error when initial conditions is passed as parameter

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

I have a set of data that I am trying to fit to an ODE model using scipy's leastsq function. My ODE has parameters `beta` and `gamma`, so that it looks for example like this:

```
# dS/dt = -betaSI
# dI/dt = betaSI - gammaI
# dR/dt = gammaI
# with y0 = y(t=0) = (S(0),I(0),R(0))
```

The idea is to find `beta` and `gamma` so that the numerical integration of my system of ODE's best approximates the data. I am able to do this just fine using leastsq if I know all the points in my initial condition `y0`.

Now, I am trying to do the same thing but to pass now one of the entries of `y0` as an extra parameter. Here is where the Python and me stop communicating...
I did a function so that now the first entry of the parameters that I pass to leastsq is the initial condition of my variable R.
I get the following message:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Laura/Dropbox/SHIV/shivmodels/test.py", line 73, in <module>
    p1,success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, initguess, args=(simpleSIR,[y0[0]],[Tx],[mydata]))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 283, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type*
```

Here is my code. It is a little more involved that what it needs to be for this example because in reality I want to fit another ode with 7 parameters and want to fit to several data sets at once. But I wanted to post here something simpler... Any help will be very very much appreciated! Thank you very much!

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.integrate import odeint

#define the time span for the ODE integration:
Tx = np.arange(0,50,1)
num_points = len(Tx)

#define a simple ODE to fit:
def simpleSIR(y,t,params):
    dydt0 = -params[0]*y[0]*y[1]
    dydt1 = params[0]*y[0]*y[1] - params[1]*y[1]
    dydt2 = params[1]*y[1]
    dydt = [dydt0,dydt1,dydt2]
    return dydt


#generate noisy data:
y0 = [1000.,1.,0.]
beta = 12*0.06/1000.0
gamma = 0.25
myparam = [beta,gamma]
sir = odeint(simpleSIR, y0, Tx, (myparam,))

mydata0 = sir[:,0] + 0.05*(-1)**(np.random.randint(num_points,size=num_points))*sir[:,0]
mydata1 = sir[:,1] + 0.05*(-1)**(np.random.randint(num_points,size=num_points))*sir[:,1]
mydata2 = sir[:,2] + 0.05*(-1)**(np.random.randint(num_points,size=num_points))*sir[:,2]
mydata = np.array([mydata0,mydata1,mydata2]).transpose()


#define a function that will run the ode and fit it, the reason I am doing this
#is because I will use several ODE's to see which one fits the data the best.
def fitfunc(myfun,y0,Tx,params):
    myfit = odeint(myfun, y0, Tx, args=(params,))
    return myfit

#define a function that will measure the error between the fit and the real data:
def errfunc(params,myfun,y0,Tx,y):
    """
    INPUTS:
    params are the parameters for the ODE
    myfun is the function to be integrated by odeint
    y0 vector of initial conditions, so that y(t0) = y0
    Tx is the vector over which integration occurs, since I have several data sets and each 
    one has its own vector of time points, Tx is a list of arrays.
    y is the data, it is a list of arrays since I want to fit to multiple data sets at once
    """
    res = []
    for i in range(len(y)):
        V0 = params[0][i]
        myparams = params[1:]
        initCond = np.zeros([3,])
        initCond[:2] = y0[i]
        initCond[2] = V0
        myfit = fitfunc(myfun,initCond,Tx[i],myparams)
        res.append(myfit[:,0] - y[i][:,0])
        res.append(myfit[:,1] - y[i][:,1])
        res.append(myfit[1:,2] - y[i][1:,2])
    #end for
    all_residuals = np.hstack(res).ravel()
    return all_residuals
#end errfunc


#example of the problem:

V0 = [0]
params = [V0,beta,gamma]  
y0 = [1000,1]

#this is just to test that my errfunc does work well.
errfunc(params,simpleSIR,[y0],[Tx],[mydata])
initguess = [V0,0.5,0.5]

p1,success = optimize.leastsq(errfunc, initguess, args=(simpleSIR,[y0[0]],[Tx],[mydata]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the variable initguess.  The function optimize.leastsq has the following call signature:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html

It's second argument, x0, has to be an array.  Your list

```
initguess = [v0,0.5,0.5]
```

won't be converted to an array because v0 is a list instead of an int or float.  So you get an error when you try to convert initguess from a list to an array in the leastsq function.

I would adjust the variable params from

```
def errfunc(params,myfun,y0,Tx,y):
```

so that it is a 1-D array.  Make the first few entries the values of v0 then append beta and gamma to that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wanted to pass a list because that way the function would work for any length of the list. But I think that your solution does exactly what I want if I instead pass the values of V0 at the end of the list. Thanks again!

Comment: leastsq also takes a flat list, so try initguess = v0+[0.5,0.5].